# auth0 - gettning the logged on user email in the express server

Tags: reactjs, express, openid-connect, express-openid-connect

I need to get the logged on user email in my express server to determine their roles and if they can use the application. I am using social media logons but only authorised users should be able to get access the application.

OAuth0 used for authentication. Application and API setup and work
React front UI - authentication handled by "@auth0/auth0-react"
Express server express - authentication handled "oauth2-jwt-bearer"

I can call the Express APIs if the user is authenticated but I want the user email.

I tried adding the scopes at the react level

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="dev-xxxxxxx.uk.auth0.com"
      clientId="RL3xxxxxxxxxxxpJ"
        authorizationParams={{
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            audience: "http://localhost:3000",
            scope: "openid email",
        }}>
        <Root />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

At the react UI I can get the logged on user information

```
`    const {
        user,
        isLoading ,
        isAuthenticated,
    } = useAuth0();`
```

At the react level I get the bearer token to call the Express API
`const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();`

At the Express API I can't get the email

```
`console.log("/api/v1/users" + JSON.stringify(req.auth.claims.email)); - undefined 
console.log("/api/v1/users" +JSON.stringify(req.oidc)); - undefined `
```

- How do I get some logged on user identification - e.g. Email?
- Is this a sufficiently secure mechanism?

Obviously I can't pass this in as an API parameter.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the claim is 'email'? It may be 'username'. In general this is going to depend upon the claims you have defined in your OAUTH2 provider. I am only familiar with Keycloak and Azure Entra iD where usually the email address is in 'username'.

Comment: Ideally I would like to see oidc information. As so much is under the hood I am not sure but think the React to Express authentication is client flow. req.auth.claims - undefined and req.oidc - undefined. 

Auth0 - React UI - Express server and then needing to identify the React user seems like it should be a common path but I can't find an article that covers this.